Why is this not evaluated (symbolic matrices)?
On version 14.1:
j := SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}] - SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}]
j . j

gives result (-SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}] +  SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}]) . (-SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}] +  SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}]) instead of expected SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}].
MatrixPower[j,2] also is not evaluated.
P.S. Update. In the original code there is a mistake, and since it has been already answered, I will leave it as is. Actually, the definition should be j := SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}] - SymbolicIdentityArray[2]
In this case, j . j // Normal is evaluated as expected but without Normal it is evaluated to (-SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] +  SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}]) . (-SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] +  SymbolicOnesArray[{2, 2}]) instead of expected SymbolicIdentityArray[2]. Why?

Please make a more-informative title.

j is not a matrix, so MatrixPower[j,2] should throw an error.  Is that what you're complaining about?

Interesting bug: SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] . SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] -    SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] // Normal

Another: TensorExpand[j . j] - j . j // Normal is nonzero. Hmm. Maybe the [Experimental] label is an understatement.

@MichaelE2 j is symbolic matrix, and MatrixPower is claimed to support it.

nj = Normal[j] does not produce a matrix, and MatrixPower[nj, 2] gives an error, and TensorRank[j] yields 4 not 2 (ditto for nj), and TensorRank[j . j] yields 6 (ditto nj). Maybe you meant to work with {2} instead of {2, 2} symbolic arrays?
